# How to  expand aliases on any invocation of /bin/bash

Tags: bash, alias

Any of you know a way to expand an alias whenever a new shell is invoked (from any place)?

For example, my alias is:

```
alias ls='ls -F'
```

- Now if I invoke it in

  ```
  grep -l ramesh | xargs ls
  ```

  … here I should get the `ls -F` output.
- If I do for e.g.

  ```
  cut -f 1 `ls test*`
  ```

  I should get a `ls -F` substitution.

Within a shell script, there is this option `shopt -s expand_aliases` but how do I get it everywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `ls` isn't actually invoked by your shell in the first example, the alias doesn't work with `xargs`.

Aliases aren't exported to subshells, that's why the second example fails.

Since aliases are evaluated after a line is read, you cannot e.g. `foo=$( alias ls='ls -l' ; ls )` either.

---

To get the desired effect in `bash` only, you can use functions, e.g.

```
function ls { /bin/ls -F "$@" ; }
```

you can add these to subshells like this to make it work:

```
ret=$( function ls { /bin/ls -l "$@" ; } ; ls )
```

---

The proper solution to have it work in all places where any program executes `ls`, place a script named `ls` before the actual `ls` in the search `$PATH` that calls the actual `ls` with `-F` parameter.

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/ls -F "$@"
```

Save as `/usr/local/bin/ls` and `export $PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`.

Be aware of programs that use `/bin/ls` hard-coded, and programs that parse the output of `ls` and will fail when it's a different format than expected.